# How to control the speed of an animation in a-frame?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe, webvr

```html
<a-camera id="view">
              <a-animation attribute="position" from="30 30 30" to="-1 1.5 -2" delay="100"></a-animation>
              <a-cursor color="black"/>
  </a-camera>
```

I was making a project on web VR using a-frame and there I am facing a particular problem of controlling the speed of my animation effects. Does anyone have a clue? Here was the animation speed I was trying to control:

Comment: Your question should provide (reproducible) code examples of what you tried and where your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to make the duration longer/shorter with the `dur: time[ms]` attribute:

```
<a-animation attribute="position" from="30 30 30" to="-1 1.5 -2" delay="100" 
dur="2000"></a-animation>
```

Feel free to check out the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/animations.html).